# Node y Mongoose: ¿Cómo busco documentos y los filtro en base a una propiedad de un objeto referencia?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo 2 modelos en Mongoose (usando NodeJS): Post y User

```js
//User Schema > User.model.js
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  premium: Boolean
});

module.exports = model('User', UserSchema);

// Post Schema > Post.model.js
const PostSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = model('Post', PostSchema)
```

Teniendo en cuenta estos modelos, en mi `getPosts controller` quiero sólo devolver los `posts` dependiendo de la propiedad `premium` del usuario de ese `post`.

Por ejemplo:

```
const docs = await Post.find({ 'user.premium': false })
```

Entiendo que no puedo acceder a la propiedad `premium` porque simplemente no existe hasta que el método find() concluya. El valor `true` o `false` de `user.premium` lo tomo de las `query params`.

Lo que quiero saber es si hay alguna manera de lograr esto. Gracias y espero puedan darme una mano.

Comment: No veo que uses [`populate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), por lo tanto tu consulta no devolverá el campo `user` tal como esperas. Por otro lado, yo no me preocuparía en traer todos los usuarios de la DB (sean `premium` o no), ya que una vez obtenidos los mismo, podría filtrar según sea apropiado. Si lo que deseas es que la consulta venga filtrada desde la DB, te sugiero usar un método de [agregación](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate) en Mongoose. Saludos

Comment: Es que populate() actúa una vez devuelto los datos con find. En fin, de última los filtro a mano, y la paginación también debería de hacerla a mano. Voy a leer un poco más sobre el método de agregación quizás me sirve. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: ¿Deseas realizar sólo 1 consulta a la DB?, es lo que entiendo de tu comentario. Entonces si o si debes usar un método de agregación para realizar la consulta.

Comment: En lo posible prefiero hacer solo 1 consulta a la DB por cuestiones de performance. Me darías un ejemplo del método de agregación en lo posible? Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lograr la consulta en 1 sola petición a la base de datos, puedes usar un método de [agregación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/index.html).

En este caso el proceso de agregación va a requerir las siguiente etapas:

1. [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/): Nos permite realizar consultas no correlacionadas entre dos colecciones. En este caso vamos a extraer datos de la colección `users` usando un `lookup` desde la colección `posts`.
2. [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/): El resultado de la etapa `lookup` devuelve un `array` con los objetos que coincidan, por eso es necesario sacar los mismos como un campo distinto de un `array`. Para lograrlo usaremos `$unwind` que separa los documentos en la cantidad de documentos que contenga el `array`. Dado que sólo se tiene un documento, simplemente reemplazará el `array` por el objeto.
3. [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/): En esta etapa filtraremos los documentos por medio del campo `user.premium`, y podremos pasar como valor el parámetro recibido en `req.parmas`.

Para usar la agregación en Mongoose, usaremos el método [`aggregate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate) del modelo, de la siguiente forma:

```js
// El modelo aobre el que aplicaremos el metodo aggregate es Post

postAggregate = Post.agregate([
  {
    // etapa $lookup
    $lookup:
      {
        from: 'users', // <- nombre de la colección de donde se extrae la data
        localField: 'user', // <- nombre del campo local (post.user) que tiene la referencia a users
        foreignField: '_id', // <- nombre del campo de la colección users al que se hace la referencia
        as: 'user' // <- nombre del campo que almacenará el resultado (se sobreescribe post.user)
      }
    },
    // etapa $unwind
    {
      $unwind: '$user' // <- nombre del campo que contiene el array de objetos
    },
    // etapa $match
    {
      $match: {
        'user.premium': req.params.premium // <- condición que se evaluará para filtrar el resultado
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Ahora solo basta usar el método `exec()` de tu agregación para obtener el resultado:

```js
const docs = await postAggregate.exec(); // <- ejecuta la consulta
```

Así, logras realizar el filtrado de lo que necesitas usando una sola consulta a la BD, dejando que el motor de la misma realice la tarea de filtrado.

Recuerda usar bloques `try catch` cuando trabajas con `async/await`

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Tu aporte la verdad que es genial! Me aclaraste la vida! Gracias!!